# I have a black background when using flutter_tex, how do I set a white background?

Tags: flutter, frontend, latex

It sounds like a very simple question, but the code just doesn't work. I say "white", the app says "black", don't know why.

I'm using Flutter 2.5.1 with flutter_tex 4.0.3 (I want to display equations).

Here is my code :

```dart
class Maths extends StatelessWidget {
  const Maths({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // this is the example from the documentation on pub.dev (simplified)
    return TeXView(
      child: const TeXViewDocument(
        r"""
          When \(a \ne 0 \), there are two solutions to \(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\) and they are
          $$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$""",
        style: TeXViewStyle(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red, // works, except for Colors.white.
          contentColor: Colors.blue, // works perfectly fine
        ),
      ),
      style: const TeXViewStyle(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red, // works, except for Colors.white
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The only problem is the black blackground behind the equation, I just want it white ;(

Please help me, I don't understand a thing with flutter_tex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed my problem. This was clearly the oddest bug I've ever seen in my life. The problem came from the dark mode of my android phone.......

I'll have to find how we force the white mode now...